# JS Apply style on every element except specified

Tags: javascript, css

I need to apply style on all allements in specified area except a specified one with JS.
How do I do that?
I couldn't find any solutions.
THank you in advance!

Comment: Can you include your code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do `document.querySelectorAll("parent *:not(#target')")` and then add whatever style.

```js
document.querySelectorAll('div *:not(#target').forEach((el) => el.style.color = 'red');
```

```html
<div>
    <span>Hello</span> <span>World</span>
    <span>Hello</span> <span>World</span>
    <span>Hello</span> <span>World</span>
    <span>Hello</span> <span>World</span>
    <span id="target">Hello</span> <span>World</span>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you, I didn't know I was able to use :not etc in .querySelectorAll()